# ¿Como eliminar un objeto de un array de objetos en javascript con base al valor de un atributo?

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

Fuera de la función [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) y por medio de índices, me gustaría saber si existe algún algoritmo o método permita eliminar el un objeto de un array por medio del valor de alguno de sus atributos.

El problema planteado es el siguiente: Tengo un arreglo de objetos que son personas, y me interesa eliminar un elemento en base al atributo `id`. Por ejemplo, la persona con id `p3`:

```
let personas = [
  { id: 'p1', nombre: 'Luis', estatus: true },
  { id: 'p2', nombre: 'Pedro', estatus: true },
  { id: 'p3', nombre: 'Emmanuel', estatus: true },
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes combinar [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) para buscar por una propiedad y luego con [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice) eliminas el índice

```js
let personas = [
 {id:'p1', nombre:'Luis', estatus:true},
 {id:'p2', nombre:'Pedro', estatus:true},
 {id:'p3', nombre:'Emmanuel', estatus:true},
];

const personaEliminar = 'p3';

const index = personas.findIndex( x => x.id === personaEliminar );

personas.splice( index, 1 );
console.log( personas );
```

Comment: Crack! No conocía ese metodo, belleza, ahora llevare mas lejos los arreglos de objects, muchas Gracias Alberto!!!

Comment: Recuerda marcar como correcta si te funcionó, para que a otro yo ande buscando de más.

Answer (score 1):

Pues hay multiple formas, como la respuesta anterior, tambien puedes hacerlo como tu dices con `filter`, o con un `map` iterando los valores y el

```js
let personas = [{
    id: 'p1',
    nombre: 'Luis',
    estatus: true
  },
  {
    id: 'p2',
    nombre: 'Pedro',
    estatus: true
  },
  {
    id: 'p3',
    nombre: 'Emmanuel',
    estatus: true
  },
]
let idPersonaDelete = 'p3';

//usando filter
/*
personas = personas.filter(x => x.id != idPersonaDelete);
*/

//usando map
var index = personas.map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
}).indexOf(idPersonaDelete);
personas.splice(index , 1);
console.log(personas);
```

Comment: muy bien, ambas soluciones son elegantes! y funcionan, abría que ver cual se tarda menos en ejecutarse no crees?

Comment: En ese caso find Índex es mucho mas veloz, según los benchmark [benchmak fast](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4765/0/findindex-vs-map-indexof)

Answer (score 1):

Otra opcion es usar forEach y aprovechar los parametros opcionales `index,arr`
el `index` representa el indice actual del elemento que se esta ejecutando y `arr` el arreglo actual que se esta evaluando

```js
let personas = [
    { id: 'p1', nombre: 'Luis', estatus: true },
    { id: 'p2', nombre: 'Pedro', estatus: true },
    { id: 'p3', nombre: 'Emmanuel', estatus: true },
];
 
const personaEliminar = 'p3';

personas.forEach((item,index,arr)=>{
    if(item.id==personaEliminar)
    { arr.splice(index,1 )}
})

console.log(personas)
```